# JavaScript execution works on Chrome and not WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, elementor

I am running this code in Chrome console dev tools and it works:

```js
const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

if (window.location.href.indexOf("Phone") != -1) {
  $('.test111232 a').attr('href', 'tel:1 ' + params.get('Phone'));
}

if (window.location.href.indexOf("state") != -1) {
  $('.test111232234 a').attr('href', 'https://www.example.com/ddd?state=' + params.get('state'));
}
```

However, when I save the page on WordPress with the Elementor HTML widget, it only changes the first number on the page.

Any ideas?

Comment: not answer but why you don't check `params` directly?

Comment: @appleapple thanks, what do you mean by that? I did check every place where it was suppose to change based on the URI and in chrome it works for all locations yet when i save on wordpress it doesn't work

Comment: How did you "save" it on wordpress? Did you use "enqueue" method? Are you familiar with loading stylesheets and scripts onto the wordpress pages?

Comment: @Ruvee good question, through elementor, its a plugin which has a widget for code, not doing it through the backened/touching files. The weiredest thing is that I have other scripts running and everything works. When it comes to this one, for some reason, only the first attribute is changed on the page.

Comment: Do you get any warning or error in the browser console? In order to test whether it's loaded to the page or not, is to delete everything and just use ```console.log("Testing from wordpress!");```. If it's loaded to the page, in your console you'll see that test message. If you don't see that test message then you know it's not loaded at all.

Comment: @Ruvee yeah it works, thats not the issue, the code is executed but only to the first attribute on the page

Comment: @chaimsem I mean you don't need `window.location.href.indexOf("Phone") != -1`, simply use [`URLSearchParams.has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/has)

Answer (score 0):

ok so basically what fixed the error was to add this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
```

before the code above, so it looks like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

if (window.location.href.indexOf("Phone") != -1) {
  $('.test111232 a').attr('href', 'tel:1 ' + params.get('Phone'));
}

if (window.location.href.indexOf("state") != -1) {
  $('.test111232234 a').attr('href', 'https://www.example.com/ddd?state=' + params.get('state'));
}
});
</script>
```

one side point that might be relevant. I had an older version of elementor pro which could be impacting js loading through the html widget.

I had the script opening and closing tags but for some reason it wanted the function and then it worked. Could be that's the way it's suppose to be in the first place.